# Dependency Graph for Java Project

Tags: java, docker, cloud, dependency-properties, dependency-management

Is there a way to have a dependency graph of a given set of projects, which uses ivy dependencies (if possible, graphical), without having 3rd party dependencies drawn too? Or where I opt out the dependencies I'm not interested in?

I'd like to get description of the dependencies between those projects.

Comment: You may find this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002812/what-is-the-analogue-of-mvn-dependencytree-in-ivy

Answer (score 0):

If you have the generated jars you can analyze them with [JArchitect](https://www.jarchitect.com) to get the dependency graph, you can easily customize it by using cqlinq to exclude the third party libraries.